# Substring and Erase

Tags: c++, file, io, substring, erase

I am trying to create a while loop that runs as long as the string taken from a file isn't empty. I need to separate the string by spaces and save the information for future use, so I am putting the substring into an array and then removing it from the actual array. However, I keep getting an error message when I run the program, or nothing but white space gets printed. [I added a picture of the file I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbmO4.png) [and of the error message I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoEfX.jpg)

```
fstream myfile;
string line;
string info[10000];
int i=0, pos;

myfile.open("bfine_project1_input.txt");
//Check
if (myfile.fail()){
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

if (myfile.is_open()){
    while (getline (myfile,line)){
        while(line.size() !=0){
            pos = line.find(" ");
            info[i]= line.substr(0,pos);
            i++;
            cout << info[i] << endl;
            //line.erase(0, pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is info a `vector`? if so, is it sized appropriately?

Comment: info is an array

Comment: How is info declared? How is i declared? Where is i assigned? What error message are you getting?  Why does SO require a [mcve]?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. If you have an error message, post its text as a text.

Comment: You don't need to remove anything from the string `line`. Just keep copying the substrings and update the position.

Comment: You are using an IDE. It has a built-in debugger. Learn to use it. Execute the loop statement by statement, watching the value of `line`. Does `line.erase(0, pos);` do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see.

1st - You increment 'i' before printing (you store the value in info[0] and print info[1])

2nd - erase the way you are using won't erase the space " ", so find(" ") will return position 0 from the 2nd time forward.

A few adjusts can fix that. See the code below:

IMPORTANT: The way your code is written you need a space at the end of the line!

```
string line;
string info[10000];
int i=0, pos;

line = "1325356 134 14351 5153613 1551 ";
while(line.size() !=0){
    pos = line.find(" ");
    info[i]= line.substr(0, pos);
    cout << i << " " << info[i] << endl;
    line.erase(0,pos+1); //ERASE " " too!
    i++;//increment i only after everything is done!
}
```